# Can't remove company informations from stock.picking report QWEB

Tags: python-3.x, report, odoo, odoo-12, qweb

Good morning, please help me, I'd like to remove all company informations from report but it occurs an error.

Here is my code:

```
<template id="empty_report" inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard">
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='header']" position="replace">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3 mb4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//div/div/ul[@class='list-inline mb4']" position="replace">

    </xpath>
    <xpath expr="//div/div/div[@name='financial_infos']" position="replace">
        <div name="financial_infos">
        </div>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

Here is the error:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1671, in report_download
    response = self.report_routes(reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1612, in report_routes
    pdf = report.with_context(context).render_qweb_pdf(docids, data=data)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 716, in render_qweb_pdf
    bodies, html_ids, header, footer, specific_paperformat_args = self.with_context(context)._prepare_html(html)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py", line 346, in _prepare_html
    body_parent = root.xpath('//main')[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But it work perfectly when I access to PDF from this url:

http://localhost:8069/report/pdf/stock.report_deliveryslip/1

But it dosn't work when I try to access from Print button and give me the error above.

Thank you for helping!

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the company information on the report header/footer than simply used with
        web.basic_layout instead of
        web.external_layout_standard
or you can do with by your own customer header/footer. As with your code, it will be the effect on another link report too.